# Scrapy login using FormRequest.from_response() returns 412 error even with headers

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

Logging in to (Walmart) returns a 412 error while using FormRequest.from_response().

412 describes some error in preconditions so I tried manually passing all headers. Did not worked.
Also tried passing the cookies, still didn't worked. 
The said website have Form, but it passes its values to its login API so I tried making a POST request to the url of the API using postman, it did worked, transferred the idea to Scrapy, didn't worked, also, making it like that defeats the purpose of the scraper to use the functions of the website while logged in as it might not redirect to the site.

```
def parse(self, response):
        cookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid="sign-in-form",
            formdata={
                "email": "email",
                "password": "pass"
            },
            headers={'Cookie': cookie},
            callback=self.after_login
        )
```

Here's the stacktrace of the scrapy. I hid the date and time

```
<date_hidden> [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.walmart.com/account/login> (referer: None)

<date_hidden> [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (412) <POST https://www.walmart.com/account/electrode/api/signin> (referer: https://www.walmart.com/account/login)
```

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#the-network-tool on how to find out all the details that your request needs.

Answer (score 1):

412 (Precondition Failed)
The 412 error response indicates that the client specified one or more preconditions in its request headers, effectively telling the REST API to carry out its request only if certain conditions were met. A 412 response indicates that those conditions were not met, so instead of carrying out the request, the API sends this status code. This means that Your request missing something. Try to add all headers that Your browser sending. I had same issue but with GET request and adding retries with using proxies also helped me.